# Let $f(x)\in F[x]$ ($F$ a field) be irreducible and let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$. Then $h(x)\in(f(x))\Leftrightarrow h(\alpha)=0$?

Tags: ideals, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field and $f(x)$ an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ such that $\alpha$ is a root of it: $f(\alpha)=0$. Now, let $(f(x))\subset F[x]$ denote the ideal generated by $f(x)$. My question is: given an arbitrary polynomial $h(x)\in F[x]$, is it true that $h(x)\in (f(x)) \Leftrightarrow h(\alpha)=0$?

The $\Rightarrow$ is easy. But what about the $\Leftarrow$?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the evaluation homomorphism $\text{ev}_\alpha:F[x] \rightarrow F[\alpha]$ where $g(x) \mapsto g(\alpha)$.  If you haven't seen this before, you'll want to write up a quick proof that this is indeed a homomorphism.

The kernel of this homomorphism is an ideal in $F[x]$, which will be the set of all polynomials with $\alpha$ as a root.  Since $F$ is a field, then $F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain.  That is, every ideal in $F[x]$ is generated by a single element.  For completeness, you'll want to prove this fact as well.  Therefore, $\ker(\text{ev}_\alpha)$ must be generated by a single element.

Can you see why that element must be $f$?  And why $h(x) \in \langle f(x) \rangle$?

Comment: Yes! And so $h(x)$ have all the ohter roots of $f(x)$, right? Thank you very much!

Comment: Certainly, if they exist!  $h(x) = g(x)f(x)$ for some $g(x) \in F[x]$.  If you're good to go, remember to accept the answer (click the check-mark) so it no longer shows up as unanswered for future Math:SE users.  Glad I could help!